# Unable to use .bss section memory

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm trying to store a file descriptor in .bss memory for a basic Linux program that reads from one file and writes to another. I've been unable to get it to work.

The program does not return an error, but does not work correctly. It works correctly when storing the file descriptors on the stack. When I try to run the program in gdb, I get the following output: `During startup program exited normally.`

Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
.section .data

.equ SYS_EXIT,  1
.equ LINUX_SYSCALL, 0x80


.section .bss

.equ BUFFER_SIZE, 500
.equ DESCR_SIZE, 4
.lcomm BUFFER_DATA, BUFFER_SIZE
.lcomm BUFFER_IN_DESCR, DESCR_SIZE
.lcomm BUFFER_OUT_DESCR, DESCR_SIZE


.section .text


.globl _start
    _start:
    movl $7, BUFFER_IN_DESCR
    movl $SYS_EXIT, %eax
    movl $BUFFER_IN_DESCR, %ebx
    int $LINUX_SYSCALL
```

Any help much appreciated!

Question edited to be Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable as mentioned by Peter in the comments.

Comment: `movl $BUFFER_IN_DESCR, %ebx`  - the `$` in AT&T syntax is immediate constant IIRC, so this probably assembles as loading `ebx` with memory address, instead of value. Step over the code in `gdb` to see yourself, if that part of memory contains the value you stored there (it may get overwritten by buffer data, if you mess up the size of block to read, or buffer address), and how your instruction gets assembled. If you are unable to breakpoint at the start of code because of missing symbols/etc, use any invalid breakpoint + run (`b *0` I think?) - will stop on first instruction, delete BP, step.

Comment: I'm unable to step through the code, when I run the program in gdb I get the following message: `During startup program exited normally.`. Apparently my code isn't actually being executed. I tried `b *0` and it also didn't work.

Comment: get a working "hello world" example which has good instructions how to compile it and run, verify it works in your environment. Then get into it in gdb or other debugger (I don't use gdb, so I don't know what more is needed, but find again some tutorial for it). After you know how to debug a working example, return back to your code (actually first toy around with that example, to get some practice with debugging and understanding how it works), either figuring out how that one is different, or move tiny parts from it into working example, until it breaks and figure out what it was...

Comment: `movl $BUFFER_IN_DESCR, %ebx` is a mov-immediate of the address to EBX.  Perhaps you want `movl BUFFER_IN_DESCR, %ebx` to load from the static location referred to by that symbol?  That doesn't explain why you can't debug your program, so this is not a [mcve] of the main problem you're having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working on this further, the problem was the incorrect use of immediate addressing mentioned by Peter in the comments. I'm still unsure why this prevented me from running the program at all, and can only assume that this was caused by some sort of OS memory protection.

Comment: Pretty sure you were just doing something wrong, unless you're hitting a GDB bug or something.  I ran `cat > foo.S` and pasted the code in the question, then ran `gcc -g -m32 -static -nostdlib foo.S` and `gdb ./a.out`.  With `b _start`, I could single-step just fine.  It also worked if I built without `-static`, making a 32-bit PIE executable.  And if I left out `-g`.   I have GDB 8.1 on Arch Linux.